# How to move all messages in a conversation?

Tags: vba, outlook

I need to know how to move all of the messages in a conversation at once.

My macro currently reads

```
Sub Archive()
    Set ArchiveFolder = Application.GetNamespace("MAPI").GetDefaultFolder(olFolderInbox).Parent.Folders("Archive")
    For Each Msg In ActiveExplorer.Selection
        Msg.UnRead = False
        Msg.Move ArchiveFolder
    Next Msg
End Sub
```

But that only moves the latest message... and only when the conversation is fully collapsed! I can't Archive when the conversation is expanded.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to handle conversations, you'll have to do so explicitly. You can go from MailItem to its Conversation using *MailItem.GetConversation*, but you'd be better off working with conversations directly.

What you do is:

1. Get all conversation headers from the current selection
2. For each conversation, get the individual items
3. Do your archiving thing with them.

The following C# code illustrates this, and should be trivial to port to VBA.

```
Outlook.Selection selection = Application.ActiveExplorer().Selection;
Outlook.Selection convHeaders = selection.GetSelection( Outlook.OlSelectionContents.olConversationHeaders) as Outlook.Selection;
foreach (Outlook.ConversationHeader convHeader in convHeaders)
{
  Outlook.SimpleItems items = convHeader.GetItems();
  for (int i = 1; i <= items.Count; i++)
  {
    if (items[i] is Outlook.MailItem)
    {
      Outlook.MailItem mail =  items[i] as Outlook.MailItem;
      mail.UnRead = false;
      mail.Move( archiveFolder );
    }
    // else... not sure how if you want to handle different types of items as well  }
}
```

Answer (score 11):

[Paul-Jan](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6219460/how-to-make-an-outlook-macro-that-moves-all-messages-in-a-conversation/6222864#6222864) put me on the right path, so I gave him the answer. Here's my really poor VBA version (I'm missing some type casting, checking). But it does work on collapsed and expanded conversations of mail.

```
Sub ArchiveConversation()
    Set ArchiveFolder = Application.GetNamespace("MAPI").GetDefaultFolder(olFolderInbox).Parent.Folders("Archive")
    Set Conversations = ActiveExplorer.Selection.GetSelection(Outlook.OlSelectionContents.olConversationHeaders)
    For Each Header In Conversations
        Set Items = Header.GetItems()
        For i = 1 To Items.Count
            Items(i).UnRead = False
            Items(i).Move ArchiveFolder
        Next i
    Next Header
End Sub
```

Comment: is there a way of doing this on Outlook 2003?

Answer (score 5):

Anthony's answer *almost* works for me. But it doesn't work on both messages and conversations. Here's my modification:

```
Sub Archive()
    Set ArchiveFolder = Application.GetNamespace("MAPI").GetDefaultFolder(olFolderInbox).Parent.Folders("Archive")

    Dim IsMessage As Integer
    IsMessage = 0

    For Each Msg In ActiveExplorer.Selection
        Msg.Move ArchiveFolder
        IsMessage = 1
    Next Msg

    If IsMessage = 0 Then
        Set Conversations = ActiveExplorer.Selection.GetSelection(Outlook.OlSelectionContents.olConversationHeaders)
        For Each Header In Conversations
            Set Items = Header.GetItems()
            For i = 1 To Items.Count
                Items(i).UnRead = False
                Items(i).Move ArchiveFolder
            Next i
        Next Header
    End If

End Sub
```