# What TypeOf are these conversation headers?

Tags: vba, email, outlook

I am trying to file emails using a macro, but I am having issues if the user selects a conversation header. What is the `typeOf` of these headers?

[image: Conversation Header]

I am trying to obtain the parent folder when an email is selected, in order to determine whether the emails should be moved (or already have been). For a `.MailItem` I can get it using the following code:

```
Set selection = ActiveExplorer.selection
Set CurrentFolder = selection(1).Parent
```

But when only a conversation header is selected this returns an error "Run-time error '440': Array Index out of bounds."

When trying to use an if statement like this:

```
If TypeOf selection Is Outlook.MailItem Then
    Set CurrentFolder = selection(1).Parent
ElseIf TypeOf selection Is Outlook.ConversationHeader Then
    'Set CurrentFolder
Else
    'Return error
End If
```

the `.ConversationHeader` does not work, as in the `ElseIf` statement returns `False`.

What `typeof` should I be using? and what code should I then be using to find the parent folder?

Comment: I ended up getting around the problem by using `ActiveExplorer.CurrentFolder`, but I am still interested in finding out the answer to my question, if someone is willing.

Answer (score 1):

The Selection property returns a [Selection](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/outlook.selection) object, not a single item. You will need to loop through the selection items (use "`for each`" or "`for`" loop from 1 to `Selection.Count` using `Selection.Item(index)`) to get to the selected items.

You can see live Outlook objects with their properties, methods, and events using [OutlookSpy](http://www.dimastr.com/outspy/) (I am its author).

Answer (score 0):

Selection.Item(index) will throw an exception if your selection is the ConversationHeader indicated in the supplied image.

I was unable to locate an actual type of object for that heading, but there are some ways around it.  Once identified that it isn't a MailItem you can check `ActiveExplorer.Selection.GetSelection(Outlook.OlSelectionContents.olConversationHeaders)`

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/outlook.selection.getselection

Most notably, they indicate

> Calling GetSelection with olConversationHeaders as the
>   argument returns a Selection object that has the Location property
>   equal to OlSelectionLocation.olViewList.
>
> If the current view is not a conversation view, or, if
>   Selection.Location is not equal to OlSelectionLocation.olViewList ,
>   calling GetSelection with olConversationHeaders as the argument
>   returns a Selection object with Selection.Count equal to 0.

Running a quick test of this

```
Dim oSelection = Selection
Set oSelection = ActiveExplorer.Selection.GetSelection(olConversationHeaders)
Print oSelect.Count 
--returns 1 when i have that odd header selected.  
--returns 0 when you have a mailItem within the header selected
```

Furthermore, take a look at [How to move all messages in a conversation?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6219460/how-to-move-all-messages-in-a-conversation/6230090)

We can easily adjust the answers given to something along the lines of :

```
Set conversations = ActiveExplorer.Selection.GetSelection(Outlook.OlSelectionContents.olConversationHeaders)
Dim sItems As SimpleItems
    For Each Header In conversations
        Set Items = Header.GetItems()
        For i = 1 To Items.Count
            If TypeOf Items(i) Is Outlook.MailItem Then
            Debug.Print (Items(i).Parent)
            End If
        Next i
    Next Header
End Sub
```

Notably this only returned headers for emails in the selected group that were IN the folder the selection was made.  I believe you'd have to further up the ante-by going into the getConversations and Conversations objects to travel down/upstream.